# No partition table on volume created from Amazon Linux 2 AMI's snapshot

Tags: partition-table, volume, amazon-linux

I have created a new AMI using Amazon Linux 2 (AL2) as source image using packer.
Now I am trying create vhd of it and transfer to Azure Image.
We have been doing this for Centos7 AMI successfully, this is first time we doing for AL2.
As part of this vhd creation,

1. we create the volume out of AL2's snapshot
2. Attach the volume to EC2 instance (Centos based)
3. Convert that block device to img file (Virtual disk image) using `dd if=/dev/nvme1n1 of=/$tmp/$imgfile bs=1M`
4. Then map it to loop device using commands -

```
lodevice=$(losetup -f)
losetup $lodevice $tmp/$imgfile
kpartx -av $lodevice
lodev=$(echo $lodevice| awk -F "/" '{print $NF}')
xfs_admin -U generate /dev/mapper/${lodev}p1
mount /dev/mapper/${lodev}p1 $tmp/image/
```

Here `kpartx -av $lodevice` command is success but loop mapper device is not getting created, when checked further, there are no partition tables on the img / loop device -

```
]# fdisk -l /mnt/ephemeral/AL2.img

Disk /mnt/ephemeral/AL2.img: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

]# fdisk -l $lodevice

Disk /dev/loop0: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad, I was creating volume from wrong snapshot, which was not created from root device. Closing it.